# How to Append Next Line to Current Line

Tags: perl

I am struggling to find a way to append the next line to the current line if the timestamp matches.  Here is my code so far:

```
open(FH, "error_log:);
@data = <FH>
foreach $line (@data) {
        if ( ($line =~ /notice/)) {  
                $line =~ s/ /,/g;    
                my @L1 = split(/|notice|\[|\]|,mpmstats:,|\t|rdy,|bsy,
+|rd,|wr,|ka,|log,|dns,|cls,|bsy:,|in,|/, $line);
                $line =~ s/|notice|\[|\]|,mpmstats:,|\t|rdy,|bsy,|rd,|
+wr,|ka,|log,|dns,|cls,|bsy:,|in,//g;                    
                print $line;
```

Note that I printed only to see the output. Output is the following:

```
Wed,Jun,13,10:40:35,2012,758,42,0,29,11,0,0,2
Wed,Jun,13,10:40:35,2012,29,mod_was_ap22_http.c
Wed,Jun,13,10:41:35,2012,761,39,0,34,5,0,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,10:41:35,2012,34,mod_was_ap22_http.c
Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,769,31,0,22,6,0,0,3
Wed,Jun,13,10:42:35,2012,22,mod_was_ap22_http.c
Wed,Jun,13,10:43:35,2012,754,46,0,29,17,0,0,0
```

I would like the number (29 on the 2nd line) placed in csv form after the others on the first line corresponding to the timestamp. THe rest of the line can be deleted.  If the line has nothing below (ex. last line) I would like to append a zero. Thank you for your help.

Here is a part of the input data as requested:

```
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:24 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.9     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:25 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.9     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:25 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.8     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:28 2012    [error  [client 10.119.116.8    File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:28 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.8     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:34 2012    [notice     mpmstats: rdy 786 bsy 14 rd 0 wr 11 ka 3 log 0 dns 0 cls 0 
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:34 2012    [notice     mpmstats: bsy: 11 in mod_was_ap22_http.c   
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:34 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.9     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
[Wed Jun 13 01:41:35 2012    [error  [client 10.119.84.9     File does not exist: /ebiz/b2b/IHS70prd/htdocs/offline.b2bonline.html
```

Comment: Your `split` looks really weird. How about you show some of the actual input data? If you use `foreach` you cannot look at two lines at once. You could use a C-style `for` loop to do that.

Comment: I have updated with input data.  Thanks, I will look into using a for loop.

Comment: I am concerned that you are going about this the wrong way. You are removing all the labels from the data, but from your sample it looks like it isn't positional. For instance the first `[notice` line contains `rdy/bsy/rd/wr/ka` etc. while the second has just `bsy/in`. Don't you need to keep track of what the values mean? Please could you show a lot more sample data containing `[notice` lines, as it looks like these are the only ones you are interested in.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't really need to keep track of what the values mean as I will be placing them in a CSV.  There I can just insert a column header string before I input the data.  At first the data was positional (they were all the same format) but I have been notified that values in the line beneath are needed as well.  These values are different from the first row.  Thank you for your previous post on the other thread btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is very strange. Usually, I see matched square brackets.

That aside, what you want is something like this:

```
# This assumes you have Perl 5.10 or autodie installed: failures in open, readline, 
# or close will die automatically
use autodie;

# chunks of your input to ignore, see below...
my %ignorables = map { $_ => 1 } qw(
    [notice mpmstats: rdy bsy rd wr ka log dns cls bsy: in
);

# 3-arg open is safer than 2, lexical my $fh better than a global FH glob
open my $error_fh, '<', 'error_log'; 

# Iterates over the lines in the file, putting each into $_
while (<$error_fh>) {

    # Only worry about the lines containing [notice
    if (/\[notice/) {

        # Split the line into fields, separated by spaces, skip the %ignorables
        my @line = grep { not defined $ignorables{$_} } split /\s+/;

        # More cleanup
        s/^\[//g for @line; # remove [ from [foo

        # Output the line
        print join(",", @line);

        # Assuming the second line always has "in" in it, 
        # but this could be whatever condition that fits your data...
        if (/\bin\b/) {  # \b matches word edges, e.g., avoids matching "glint"
            print "\n";
        }
        else {
            print ",";
        }
    }
}

close $error_fh;
```

I did not compile this, so I can't guarantee that I didn't typo somewhere.

The key here is that you do the first `print` without a newline, but end with comma. Then, add the newline when you detect that this is the second line.

You could instead declare `@line` outside the loop and use it to accumulate the fields until you need to output them with the newline on the end.

Comment: It worked great for the most part!!  Only problem is that if one of the lines doesn't have a corresponding time beneath it, it will append the next available line (even if it is a different timestamp).  Any way to fix this?

Comment: In that case, you need to change the criteria for adding the newline or the ",". You could move the `if (/\bin\b/) { ... }` lines to the top and add the "\n" instead if you detect the line contains `/\brdy\b/`. You'll end up with an extra newline at the start of your output. You can clean that up by detecting if this is the first line found and skipping the newline or whatever.

Comment: Also, @Birei has a simple improvement as well. Use `next unless /\[notice\b/;` instead of the `if (/\[notice\b/) { ... }` block wrapping most of the code.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to return the array?  I attempted through a subroutine with no luck.

Comment: You can always return an array and assign it to another array outside: `sub do_it { return @inside; } my @outside = do_it();`

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`. It omits lines that don't contain **[notice**. For each line matching it increments a variable and saves different fields in an array depending if it is odd or even (first ocurrence of **[notice** or the second one).

```
perl -ane '
    next unless $F[5] eq q|[notice|;
    ++$notice;
    if ( $notice % 2 != 0 ) {
        push @data, @F[0..4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22];
        next unless eof;
    }

    push @data, (eof) ? 0 : $F[8];
    $data[0] =~ s/\A\[//;
    printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, @data;
    @data = ();
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` has content of your question, output would be:

```
Wed,Jun,13,01:41:34,2012,786,14,0,11,3,0,0,0,11
```